# Вопрос об алгоритме расширяемости скриптов в php

Tags: ооп, php, расширения, модульность

**Задача**: *написать пример скрипта* (или описать алгоритм), который сам по себе ничего не делает, а только *подключает модули*, и эти модули и *строят всю систему*.

**На PHP.**

Comment: Ну например:
1. Папка с модулями
2. Скрипт получает список файлов и директорий
3. скрипт циклом подключает модули.
А дальше самое простое: реализовать :)

Comment: @Дима Фалелеев, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да легко.

```
<?php

$allowed_modules = array('user','catalog','pictures');

function __autoload($name){
  if(in_array($name,$allowed_modules) && file_exists('/Modules/'.$name.'.php')){
    require /Modules/'.$name.'.php';
  }else{
    header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
    die('No such module');
  }
}
```

как вариант, allowed_modules можно так же получать при помощи модуля поиска доступных модулей.

Comment: Как-то не совсем в тему $allowed_modules и синтаксически не правильно.($allowed_modules = array('user','catalog','pictures');)

а уж

   header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
    die('No such module');

тем более, там надо throw new Exception('No such module')

Comment: Туплю, сорри. Про эксепшн - спорный вопрос. :) Оно его еще поймать должно успеть, не факт, что успеет.

Comment: Ну как минимум autoload ни в коем случае не должен кидать то что вы делаете сейчас :)

Comment: Должен. Потому что в ином случае за него кинет стандартный обработчик ошибок, а это гораздо хуже. 
Другое дело, что я лично рассматриваю автолоад не как средство подключения модулей, а как точку входа в аварийный режим работы, когда прочие системы graceful degradation уже не сработали. Здесь мы можем успеть записать грозную надпись в лог и тихо сдохнуть. 
Но для примера подключения модулей это вполне годится.

Comment: Ок, но с @knes я всё не согласен с

    header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
    die('No such module');

Comment: @Nord001, вы можете предложить свой, правильный, вариант в ответах к этому вопросу. Никто не обидится, а, возможно, даже плюсанут.